# Construct a Tree with list of Objects in Python

Tags: python, object, tree

I created a class that is formatted as follows:

```
class PathStructure(object):
    def __init__(self, Description, ID, Parent):
        self.Description = Description
        self.ID = ID
        self.Parent = Parent
        self.Children = []
```

Where Description, ID and Parent are strings, and Children are lists of `PathStructure` objects; thus, I know all the parent-child relationships. I want to be able to construct a graphical representation of this tree, so each `PathStructure` object becomes a node with the parent-child relationships linking the nodes. Creating the nodes is easy, I think:

```
nodes = {}
For item in pathstructure_list:
    name = item.Description
    nodes[name] = item
```

I am having trouble thinking of a way to link these nodes into create a tree structure out of the linked nodes. I have looked at examples, but I am kind of new to using dicts, so I don't really understand the solutions -- especially since I will be constructing a dict of objects.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I initialize each PathStructure object from a spreadsheet of information, and then I determine the parent-child relationships. For example:

```
first  = PathStructure('Master','1-234-5',None)
second = PathStructure('Sub One','2-345-6',first.ID)
third  = PathStructure('Sub Two','3-456-7',first.ID)
fourth = PathStructure('Sub Three','4-597-8',second.ID)

pathstructs = [first, second, third, fourth]
```

And then I determine each object's children through a function, so I know each object's parent and child.

Comment: The PathStructure makes a tree - each node has a parent and children. [Like this on the left](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Nary_to_binary_tree_conversion.png). Why do you have `pathstructure_list` ? "*so each PathStructure object becomes a node with the parent-child relationships linking the nodes.*" - but they already are that way, aren't they? "*I am having trouble thinking of a way to link these nodes into create a tree structure out of the linked nodes.*" - By setting the parent and children when you create them...? It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: pathstructure_list is a list of PathStructure objects. I first initialize these objects from a spreadsheet of information and then I determine the children of the objects: `first_obj = PathStructure('Master','01',None)` 'first_obj.Children = [first_child, second_child]` when first_child and second_child are PathStructure objects that may or may not have children. Lastly, `pathstructure_list = [first_obj, first_child, second_child]`. I edit my post to describe this better.

Comment: instead of passing the `.ID` of the parent as the Parent, try passing the `PathStructure` object that is the parent as the parent, then you can `.append(self)` to `parent.children` to establish the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get close to where I want to be with the following:

```
full = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for item in pathstructs:
    name = item.Description
    ident = item.ID
    perent = item.Parent
    final = full[ident]

    if parent:
        full[parent][ident] = final
    else:
        root = final
```

But this method gets rid of the PathStructure objects, so I am stuck with a tree of string instead of object.